# Setting a focus with a blinking cursor on a textinput control in Adobe Air

Tags: air

How to set focus with blinking cursor on a textinput control in Adobe Air?

Comment: Hi, did my answer wind up helping you? If so, please mark it as accepted. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the FocusManager class and the setFocus() method. An example is [here](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/09/23/setting-focus-in-flex-using-the-focus-manager/).

Comment: Thanks whybird for your answer but this is not working for me.
My question was not clear.
I have a login form in adobe air with 2 controls (user name and password) and I want to set the focus with blinking cursor to the username control after the form is totally loaded and without click any buttom

Comment: You mean an HTML form inside the air app? Then instead of
 usernameButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, usernameButton_click);
make it html.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, usernameButton_click); (only for future readability, don't name the function _click, because it has nothing to do with clicking any more). As seen on http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=HandlingHTMLEvents_1.html